# Problem with jQuery if, else if, else - Populating form field with jQuery using Quill and Memberstack data

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, quill

,I've got a form that is automatically populated with data from Memberstack using attributes to dynamically update input values with what is stored in the member database. The user can then edit those values and submit the form to update their member data.

There's a Bio field and a Locations field, each with a Quill rich text editor. On submit, the rich text is converted to HTML and stored in Memberstack that way.  If we try to pre-populate the Quills with data from Memberstack, they break and won't allow the user to edit the data. So, to display the user's current Bio and Locations, we call that data onto the page and display it as rich text, with an empty Quill editor below it for the user to be able to type in new Bio or Locations data.

However, if the Quill is empty on submit, it will replace the stored field value with "`<p><br></p>`".

Since there are two data fields–and two Quills–but we can only have a single function trigger on submit, we're trying to use an if, else if, else if, else statement. However, it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

We currently have a hidden text block with an id of #bio_hidden that calls in the Bio stored in Memberstack, and the same for locations with #locations_hidden - to be used as a reference

Then there's two Quills for Bio and Locations

Finally there's the actual fields that are used to update the data in the database (just called bio and locations)

The logic we're going for is:

if quillBio **and** quillLocations are empty:
bio = bioHidden, locations = locationsHidden

else if just quillBio is empty:
bio = bioHidden, locations = quillLocations

else if just quillLocations is empty:
bio = quillBio, locations = locationsHidden

else
bio = quillBio, locations = quillLocations

However, whether the Quills are empty or have been edited, the data that's getting passed through the form and updating the database is always just what is in the hidden fields.

Here's the script:

```
<script>
var quillBio = new Quill('#editor_bio', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic'],
      ['link'],
      [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Type here',
  theme: 'snow'
});

var quillLocations = new Quill('#editor_locations', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic'],
      ['link'],
      [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Type here',
  theme: 'snow'
});

var bioHidden = document.getElementById('bio_hidden');
var locationsHidden = document.getElementById('locations_hidden');
var bio = document.querySelector('textarea[name=bio]');
var locations = document.querySelector('textarea[name=locations]');

var form = document.querySelector('form[name=medical-update-form]');
form.onsubmit = function() {  
  // Populate hidden form on submit
    if((quillBio.root.innerHTML == "<p><br></p>" || "")&&(quillLocations.root.innerHTML == "<p><br></p>" || "")) {
        bio.value = bioHidden.root.innerHTML;
    locations.value = locationsHidden.root.innerHTML;
    }else if(quillBio.root.innerHTML == "<p><br></p>" || ""){
    bio.value = bioHidden.root.innerHTML;
    locations.value = quillLocations.root.innerHTML;
    }
    else if(quillLocations.root.HTML == "<p><br></p>" || ""){
    bio.value = quillBio.root.innerHTML;
    locations.value = locationsHidden.root.innerHTML;
        }else{
    bio.value = quillBio.root.innerHTML;
    locations.value = quillLocations.root.innerHTML;
    }
    
    console.log("Submitted", $(form).serialize(), $(form).serializeArray());
    // No back end to actually submit to!
  return false;
};

</script>
```

Comment: What is meant by `if((quillBio.root.innerHTML == "<p><br></p>" || "")...`? Empty string is "falsy", so why bother checking it? Or do you mean `if((quillBio.root.innerHTML == "<p><br></p>" || quillBio.root.innerHTML == "")...`?

Comment: yes, that's what i was going for–just as a safeguard in case there's a scenario where the Quill doesn't automatically fill the input with that empty HTML. i didn't realize i needed to specify the quillBio.root.innerHTML the 2nd time, thanks for pointing that out.